# How to run IBM Watson Text to speech in browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, websphere, ibm-cloud, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

Can anyone tell me how to use my IAM api key and url to perform text to speech on a string stored on a variable and play the synthesized speech audio from within the browser?
The WebSocket interface example gives me an authentication error, which leads to the download of a 0KB .oga file, which doesn't make any sense.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

These 3 resources might help target where you're having issues:

- [Javascript SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk) for speech
- The [code](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/text-to-speech-nodejs) behind the [demo](https://text-to-speech-demo.ng.bluemix.net/)
- The [API reference](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/text-to-speech?code=node#synthesize-audio)